# How to convert nvarchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have fields with decimal values but imported in database as `nvarchar(50)` data type, that look like this:

| Time | (Ordered product sales) | (Units ordered) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01T00:00:00 | $55.60 | 4 |
| 2022-01-03T00:00:00 | $652.54 | 13 |

**Goal**: I wanted to aggregate (SUM) these fields to get the sum of orders and total number of units ordered

I tried to cast these values as `numeric(10,2)` because I wanted to aggregate these fields (SUM):

```
SELECT 
    [Time],
    SUM(CAST([Ordered_product_sales] AS NUMERIC(10, 2))) AS Sales_per_day,
    SUM(CAST([Units_ordered] AS INT)) AS num_of_units_ordered
FROM 
    [dbo].[salesDashboard]
WHERE      
    Ordered_product_sales <> '0.00' 
    AND Ordered_product_sales IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    Time
```

However, I am getting a following error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: Use try_convert(money,[Ordered_product_sales]) ... it tends to be a little more forgiving.  For example:  select try_convert(money,'$55.60')

Comment: Or `replace(MyColumn,'$','')` first

Comment: Of course, the real solution is to fix your design and not store numerical data as an `nvarchar`.

Comment: @Larnu The database has some million rows and data is uncleaned, numerical fields must go as `nvarchar` since there are mutiple data types in just one field.

Comment: *numerical fields must go as nvarchar since there are multiple data types in just one field* - and that **of course** is another **horribly bad design** ... fix that, instead of wasting your time applying fixes and band-aids to all your queries!

Comment: This certainly sounds like you aren't telling us the whole story and that, like mentioned, you have some very fundamental design problems you need to address.

Comment: DaleK points to the immediate cause of your error: the '$' character isn't able to be converted to a numeric and must be removed from the string before the `CAST`.
Larnu and marc_s are also correct in being critical of the design of the table and columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue causing your error is that the data strings in the [Ordered_product_sales] column contain a character that cannot be converted to a `numeric` data type. You must first sanitize the strings to remove all characters that cannot be converted, specifically the `$` present in your sample data, prior to performing the `CAST` function.

This should work:

```sql
SELECT 
    [Time]
    ,SUM(CAST(REPLACE([Ordered_product_sales], '$', '') AS NUMERIC(10, 2))) 
     AS Sales_per_day,
    ,SUM(CAST([Units_ordered] AS INT)) AS num_of_units_ordered
FROM [dbo].[salesDashboard]
```

And you should put some thought and effort into improving the design of your table and columns with respect to datatypes.